# Solve $(-3 - i)^{\frac{5}{7}}$ using de Moivre formula

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$\text{I tried the following: } |2|^{5/7}(\cos(5/7(-\pi/6 + 2k\pi))+ i\sin(5/7(-\pi/6+2k\pi)))
 $$

I don't know how to complete from here. I am also having trouble with "2k$\pi$" as a lot of times I don't know if I should multiply with exponent of the complex number or not, and if there is denomenator underneath it or not, it confuses me.

Comment: De Moivre's formula only works for integers which is not the case of $\frac{5}{7}$, what is you definition of $z^{\gamma}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien The definition is $z^\gamma= |z|^\gamma(\cos(\gamma*\phi)+ i\sin(\gamma*\phi)))$

Comment: And what is $\phi$ ? Because there are multiple $\phi$ such that $z=|z|e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien $\phi$ is the angle between x axis and complex number

Comment: I mean, in what interval belongs $\phi$ ? For instance $-1=e^{i\pi}=e^{-i\pi}$ and thus $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=|(-1)|^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)=i$ with the first identity, with the second one you get $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=|(-1)|^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)=-i$ and the definition is not a definition because there is no unique $\phi$ such that $z=|z|e^{i\phi}$, unless you impose $\phi$ to be in an interval of length $2\pi$, so in what intervall does $\phi$ belong ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the meaning of a "fractional exponent" in case of a complex number as its base? Whosoever gave you that question in THAT form ought to scratch behind his ears. Take for example $\sqrt{i}$. There is no unique solution to this either, but we DO have 2 solutions to $x^2=i$. So in your case, we are essentially interested in $x^7=(-3-i)^5$. Now this can be done with DeMoivre. Finding out the 5th power isn't to bad and then extracting 7 roots is also just some annoying algebra. And so yes, as a 7th degree equation we expect 7 solutions. Do you know how to do $x^7=12-316i$? (absolute value, argument, etc) The algebra isn't pretty